# SD Card corrupts 3rd and 5th file

Tags: formatting, sd-card, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

I bought a SanDisk Extreme 64GB SD Card a few weeks ago which I accidentally removed from the card reader while it was formatting. I use it with my DSLR and format before every shoot.

This corrupted most of the card but I managed to fix it with formatting and `chkdsk <drive> /r`, which now reports the card as being fine and free of errors.

Unfortunately, with some testing I have found that problems still persist.

For some weird reason when I go to playback any of my images, all of them are perfectly fine except the 3rd and 5th one. This suggests that there is still something on the card that formatting and *chkdsk* didn't remove and causes this malfunctioning.

This happened to another card of mine a while back, 2GB, whereby the only the 2nd image cannot load and causes similar crashes of programs like Windows Image Viewer and Adobe Lightroom.

Does anyone know what is causing this and (hopefully) how to fix it?

Comment: that sounds like a hardware problem to me.  Formatting should have cleared out any data corruption issues caused by unsafely removing the drive (because there was no more data to be corrupted); since it's persisting, that suggest to me that something is wrong with the hardware.  Consider a warranty replacement if that is an option,.

Comment: David it sounds like you're using windows, did you format with "Quick Format checked or unchecked? Theres a rather big difference in the result of those two operations.

Answer (score 0):

Given the current cost of SD cards, I'd recommend backing up any data you can still read from the card and replacing it -- either under warranty, if available from the manufacturer, or out of pocket.  Your data is almost certainly worth more than a few dollars worth of hardware.